How to join aggregated values from a different table to a filtered and paginated resultset
I'm trying to get products and their aggregated group information. I have three tables on Postgresql database: product, product_group, and product_group_product. This is how the end result should look like:



Id
Name
Other product columns
total
group_names
group_ids




1
product A
...
456
group1&group2
101&102


2
product B
...
456
group3
103



This is what I came up with:
WITH filtered_products AS (
    SELECT 
        product.*,
        COUNT(*) OVER () AS total
    FROM product
    WHERE seller_uuid = '<seller-uuid>'
        AND (product.last_update IS NULL OR product.last_update < '2024-12-19 11:00:00')
    ORDER BY product.loaded_plugin_set asc NULLS FIRST, product.uuid ASC
    LIMIT 200 OFFSET 0
), group_info AS (
    SELECT
        product_uuid,
        string_agg(replace(product_group.name, '&', '_'), '&' ORDER BY product_group.id) AS group_names,
        string_agg(product_group.id::text, '&' ORDER BY product_group.id) AS group_ids
    FROM filtered_products
    LEFT JOIN product_group_product
        ON product_group_product.seller_uuid = filtered_products.seller_uuid
        AND product_group_product.product_uuid = filtered_products.uuid
    LEFT JOIN product_group
        ON product_group_product.seller_uuid = product_group.seller_uuid
        AND product_group_product.product_group_uuid = product_group.uuid
GROUP BY product_uuid
)
SELECT
    filtered_products.*,
    group_info.group_names,
    group_info.group_ids
FROM filtered_products
LEFT JOIN group_info
    ON filtered_products.uuid = group_info.product_uuid;

(Example query for getting products that didn't get any updates within the last 2 hours)
It's used for pagination and filtering on products. WHERE and ORDER BY statements on the filtered_products CTE is dynamically created by the backend. Fields can be changed depending on the columns selected on the UI.
This is taking 11 seconds for a user with ~2.9M products. Here's the plan: https://explain.depesz.com/s/APlM
Is there a way to further optimize this query? What's the best way to join aggregated values from a different table to filtered products?

Hi, and welcome to dba.se! Could you please go to dbfiddle and provide some sample data and your desired result? In particular, please show us the relationshp(s) between product, product_group, and product_group_product (Foreign Keys &c.).
